# Microsoft Ajax Minifier and NAnt

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, nant, nant-task

Could someone explain to me how to use the [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=34488) from a nant-script as a nant-task. I've seen examples of how to use it in Visual Studio but I would like the minification to be done on our CI-server.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure specifically about the MS Ajax Minifier, but here's what I did to get the [Yahoo! UI Library: YUI Compressor for .Net](http://www.codeplex.com/YUICompressor) working.

1. Downloaded the YUI Compressor
   assemblies for .NET
2. Modified their [Sample MSBuild.xml File](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sample%20MSBuild.xml%20File&ProjectName=yuicompressor)
3. Modified my nAnt script to run the MSBuild task (more details here: [Build and publish .Net 2.0 projects with NAnt and the MSBuild task](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeffrey.palermo/archive/2006/08/12/148248.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

This is the code i use, it minifies all *.js and *.css in a folder using ajaxminifier

```
<foreach item="File" property="filename">
    <in>
        <items>
            <include name="${deployment.dir}\js\*.js"></include>        
            <include name="${deployment.dir}\css\*.css"></include>
        </items>
    </in>
    <do>
        <echo message="Minifying ${filename} and overwritting file"/>
        <exec program="${ajaxminifier.exe}"
            workingdir="."
            failonerror="true"
            commandline='-clobber:true ${filename} -o ${filename}'/>
    </do>
    </foreach>
```

Note that this script overwrites the files with the minified version ( with -clobber:true arg). ${ajaxminifier.exe} is the path to ajaxmin.exe

Answer (score 0):

```
<foreach item="File" property="Debugfile" >
    <in>        
        <items>
            <include name="**\*.debug.js"/>
        </items>
    </in>
    <do failonerror="false">
        <regex pattern="^(?'filename'.*)\.(?'extension2'\w+)\.(?'extension3'\w+)$" input="${Debugfile}" />
        <regex pattern="^(?'path'.*(\\|/)|(/|\\))(?'file'.*)$" input="${Debugfile}" />
        <echo message="renaming with filename=${path},file=${file}"/>
        <exec program="${Minifie.lib}\ajaxmin.exe" commandline="${filename}.debug.js -o ${filename}.js" failonerror="true"/>
    </do>
</foreach>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    description="AjaxminFilesCreation.">
    <foreach item="File" property="Debugfile" >
        <in>        
            <items>
            <include name="**\*.debug.js"/>
        </items>
        </in>
        <do failonerror="false">

        <regex pattern="^(?'filename'.*)\.(?'extension2'\w+)\.(?'extension3'\w+)$" input="${Debugfile}" />
        <regex pattern="^(?'path'.*(\\|/)|(/|\\))(?'file'.*)$" input="${Debugfile}" />
        <echo message="renaming with filename=${path},file=${file}"/>
    <exec program="${Minifie.lib}\ajaxmin.exe" commandline="${filename}.debug.js -o ${filename}.js" failonerror="true"/>
        </do>
    </foreach>
</target>
```